# on key press append value to hidden field but not the whole value

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a input field :

```
<input id="txt-ssn" name="txt-ssn" type="text" maxlength="9" data-checkno="true">
```

if user type on hidden field value should save in hidden field like :

```
<input id="txt-ssn" name="txt-ssn" type="hidden" maxlength="9" data-checkno="true">
```

but problem is :
if want to convert word in `*`
so if i am appending value its is taking `*` as well  like :

*******7 is getting store in my hidden input but it should be `1234567`

```
$("#txt-ssn").blur(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("#txt-ssn-hidden").val(value);
    if (!isNaN(value)) {
        $(this).attr("data-checkno","true");
    }
    else if(isNaN(value)) {
        $(this).removeAttr("data-checkno");
    }
    $(this).val(value.replace(/[^\s]/g, "*")); 
});
```

**Update**

I dont want to use input type password

Comment: why don't you give input type="password" a try? This input will exactly behave like you want, hiding the input chars after a moment with * but you can get it via value though.

Comment: Just use a `<input type="password">`

Comment: some project requirement

Comment: this is not a duplicate as i dont want input type password

Comment: @Cerbrus can you please remove this form duplicate as my req is different i dont want to use type password

Comment: ... Why wouldn't you?

Comment: How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/bmartinelle/vuwux52p/
Just listen to the keyup event

Comment: @Cerbrus If SachinRawal wants to manually recreate input type password with jQuery, this isn't a duplicate of a question where input type password is the correct answer.

Comment: I'll re-open this when the OP answers why `type="password"` isn't an option. This smells like an XY issue to me.

Comment: fair enough :) @SachinRawal?

Comment: it just a client requirement.what else i can say.. client dont want black dot. :) @Cerbrus

Comment: @florian did you check the question ?? i dont have input type password and i dont want to use input type password....

Comment: I think explicitly wanting to approach a known solution differently, such as input password, is acceptable as a new question @Cerbrus, no?

Comment: @SachinRawal: The point here is that it is a very bad idea to "emulate" a `type="password"`. Just use the native elements. Tell the client that it's technically impossible to change the shown characters. Or tell them that the technology is unreliable (Which wouldn't be a lie)

Comment: @Cerbrus I retract my previous statements :) I quickly realized how not a good idea this is when attempting to account for keyboard usage. Geez what a rabbit hole lol

Comment: @SachinRawal check out this fiddle if the black dot is the only reason for this inquiry http://jsfiddle.net/estelle/8WpNg/